# React : Filter or map Object by iterating through list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have list of CutomerType objects and Customer object. Customer object has the cutomerType id property on it. Based on the customer type id on customer object I have to loop over or map the right customerType object and disaplay the name code.

```html
[ {
  "id" : "5436d5fd-e3ea-4e09-be4a-a80967cd72e5",
  "code" : "0",
  "name" : "UN"
}, {
  "id" : "674b76b8-f1ac-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code" : "1",
  "name" : "NON-UN"
}, {
  "id" : "674b76b8-f1ad-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code" : "2",
  "name" : "COS-UN"
}, {
  "id" : "674b76b8-f1ae-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code" : "NA",
  "name" : NA"
} ]


Customer
{
  "id" : "1",
   "name": "Jhon",
   "type": "5436d5fd-e3ea-4e09-be4a-a80967cd72e5",   
}
```

Comment: did you mean to use <select> tag?

Comment: Just FYI the option tag [is not valid inside a div](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-option-element.html)

Comment: @Marie Its react js working as per my requirement.

Comment: @HermanStarikov The result should not display all the list values only one select value based on the id

Comment: @ssl Regardless of the react working for you, HTML has rules. if you violate those rules are are going to run into annoying issues and inconsistencies between browsers or flat out broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could do.

```js
const customerCodeArray = [{
  "id": "5436d5fd-e3ea-4e09-be4a-a80967cd72e5",
  "code": "0",
  "name": "UN"
}, {
  "id": "674b76b8-f1ac-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code": "1",
  "name": "NON-UN"
}, {
  "id": "674b76b8-f1ad-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code": "2",
  "name": "COS-UN"
}, {
  "id": "674b76b8-f1ae-5c14-e053-ce5e1cac867d",
  "code": "NA",
  "name": "NA"
}]


const customer = {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jhon",
  "type": "5436d5fd-e3ea-4e09-be4a-a80967cd72e5",
};

const getCustomerCode = (type) => {
  const filterList = customerCodeArray.filter((obj) => obj.id === type);
  if (filterList.length > 0) {
    return filterList[0];
  }
}
console.log(getCustomerCode(customer.type));
```

Comment: Why check if any item exists before returning when you dont return a default value anyways? Just return `customerCodeArray.filter((obj) => obj.id === type)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is clear, if not feel free to ask

```
const loop = // whole array;
const customer = // customer object
loop.find(el => el.id === customer.type).name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredResult = customerCodeArray.filter(type => type.id === Customer.type);

console.log(filteredResult[0].name);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value